# Как переориентировать AJAX на работу с JSON вместо XML?

Tags: php, ajax, json

Есть стандартное AJAX приложение. Как в нем сделать функцию-обработчик полученного после php обработки json? Вот это php файл-обработчик.

```
    $login = $_GET['login'];
$Names = R::findOne('users','login = ?',array($login));
if (!empty ($Names)) {
    $data["text"] = "Увы, но ник $login уже занят";
    $data["color"] = "red";
} else {
    $data["text"] = "Да, этот ник свободен!";
    $data["color"] = "green";
}
return json_encode($data);
```

То есть оно возвращает JSON моего массива, в котором есть то, что мне нужно вывести. Но как его теперь принять?
Изначально(когда я использовал XML) был такой код:

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            Response = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.all("Message").innerHTML =  '<i>' + Response + '</i>';
            setTimeout('request()', 10000000000); 
        } else {
            alert("Error with server access");
        }
    } else {

    }
```

Что с ним нужно сделать теперь, чтобы он мог принимать JSON и выводить его?

Comment: `JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText)` после проверки статус200, и дальше что угодно делайте

Comment: Я не совсем понял. Я написал сразу после проверки статус==200 вот это: xmlResponse = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText); А дальше все также как в моем коде, но это ничерта не сработало. Можно немного более развернуто?

Comment: И еще кое-что, мой код для PHP файла верный? Просто через панель разработчика я посмотрел на ответ от сервера, и в таком виде, там пусто. Вообще.

Comment: ваш код после статус200 связанный с xml можно удалить. если `var d = JSON.parse(...)`, то далее в `d.text` будет ваше получаемое сообщение. А куда уж вы его показать хотите, решайте сами.

Comment: не знаю почему у вас там в пхп-коде написано `return json_encode()`. Если это простой пхп файл, то вам надо вывести  `echo json_encode(..)`

Comment: Мне так сказали в другом вопросе, а сам я пока не знаю, только учусь, всем большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основании комментариев, предположу следующие изменения вашего кода. С *RedBeans* я не знаком, поэтому относительно блока пхп кода сомнение вызывает лишь строка `return json_encode($data)`. Если приведенный фрагмент кода не является частью функцию или метода, то для вывода/передачи контента клиенту следует вывести полученный текст с помощью, например, `echo json_encode($data)`.

На стороне JS, когда вы получили код ответа 200, то вам необходимо взять контент ответа (текст) и с помощью `JSON.parse()` преобразовать его в JS-объект. Далее поля `data` и `color` будут содержать искомые значения.

Используемый вами метод `document.all` не является стандартным и лучше использовать `document.getElementById`, хотя проще воспользоваться библиотекой *jQuery*. Поэтому ваш JS-код становится примерно следующим:

```
if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
     var data = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
     document.getElementBy("Message").innerHTML =  '<i>' + data.text + '</i>';         
}
else {
    alert("Error with server access");
}
```

В случае использования jQuery все становится еще проще (отправка запроса и получение результата, на случай если вы не знакомы с этой библиотекой).

```
$.getJSON('check-login.php', { login: 'василий'}, function(data){
    $("#message").html("<i>" + data.text + "</i>");
});
```

Comment: Да, все заработало, большое спасибо, вы мне очень помогли.